# Extracting 'Year' out of Strings with inconsistent formatting; AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Tags: python, regex, string, attributeerror

This is a convoluted question so please review my project file [here](https://github.com/grace-radetsky/Data-analytics-with-Python/blob/main/Learning%20Regular%20Expressions.ipynb)

I have a dataframe as below and would like to extract the 'Year' (4 digits) from strings in the 'Fact' column and store the 'Year' in the 'Year' column. However, the datetimes in the 'Fact' column do not follow a consistent format as below.

```
Fact    Year
0   Population estimates, July 1, 2016, (V2016) NaN
1   Population estimates base, April 1, 2010, (V2...    NaN
2   Population, percent change - April 1, 2010 (es...   NaN
3   Population, Census, April 1, 2010   NaN
4   Persons under 5 years, percent, July 1, 2016, ...   NaN
```

I defined a pattern using regex, and use **for loop** to extract the 4 digits, however I received the AttributeError. Codes and error message are below:

```
for row in range(0, 64):
    Year = re.search(pattern1, data.iat[row, index_fact]).group()
    data.iat[row, index_year] = Year
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-48-4d5d634f47d5> in <module>
      1 for row in range(0, 64):
----> 2     Year = re.search(pattern1, data.iat[row, index_fact]).group()
      3     data.iat[row, index_year] = Year

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

And in the resulting table, some years were extracted successfully but others weren't:

```
Fact    Year
0   Population estimates, July 1, 2016, (V2016) 2016
1   Population estimates base, April 1, 2010, (V2...    2010
2   Population, percent change - April 1, 2010 (es...   2010
3   Population, Census, April 1, 2010   2010
4   Persons under 5 years, percent, July 1, 2016, ...   2016
... ... ...
59  Nonminority-owned firms, 2012   <re.Match object; span=(25, 29), match='2012'>
60  Veteran-owned firms, 2012   <re.Match object; span=(21, 25), match='2012'>
61  Nonveteran-owned firms, 2012    <re.Match object; span=(24, 28), match='2012'>
62  Population per square mile, 2010    <re.Match object; span=(28, 32), match='2010'>
63  Land area in square miles, 2010 <re.Match object; span=(27, 31), match='2010'>
```

Please let me know how to fix the AttributeError or advise any better approach to my original goal (i.e. to extract 'Year' from strings.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like [`datefinder`](https://pypi.org/project/datefinder/).

```py
>>> s = "Population estimates, July 1, 2016"
>>> list(datefinder.find_dates(s))
[datetime.datetime(2016, 7, 1, 0, 0)]
```

Should make your life a little bit easier.

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried datefinder and it works out well for strings with format such as July 1, 2016. However a few strings in the tail end ([data.tail(10)](https://prnt.sc/13no4xi) )had only the 'year' such as 2012 so datefinder returns an empty list for those lines ([please view screenshot](https://prnt.sc/13no3af)). Could you please advise how to fix this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would use `str.extract` here with an appropriate regex pattern:

```py
df["Year"] = df["Fact"].str.extract(r'\b\w+ \d+, (\d{4})\b')
```

For regular Python, use `re.findall`:

```py
years = re.findall(r'\b\w+ \d+, (\d{4})\b', fact)
```